# print the closure definition/source in Groovy

Tags: groovy, closures

Anyone who knows how the print the source of a closure in Groovy?

For example, I have this closure (binded to `a`)

```
def a = { it.twice() }
```

I would like to have the `String`  "it.twice()" or "{ it.twice() }"

Just a simple `toString` ofcourse won't work:

```
a.toString(); //results in: Script1$_run_closure1_closure4_closure6@12f1bf0
```

Comment: This probably won't match your circumstance, but you might be able to go the other way. Since GroovyShell.evaluate() executes a String (with appropriate var bindings), what if the closure was simply a string?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

short answer is you can't. long answer is:
depending on what you need the code for, you could perhaps get away with

```
// file: example1.groovy
def a = { it.twice() }
println a.metaClass.classNode.getDeclaredMethods("doCall")[0].code.text
// prints: { return it.twice() }
```

BUT
you will need the source code of the script available in the classpath AT RUNTIME as explained in

> groovy.lang.MetaClass#getClassNode()
>   "Obtains a reference to the original
>   AST for the MetaClass if it is
>   available at runtime
>   @return The
>   original AST or null if it cannot be
>   returned"

AND
the *text* trick does not really return the same code, just a code like representation of the AST, as can be seen in this script

```
// file: example2.groovy
def b = {p-> p.twice() * "p"}
println b.metaClass.classNode.getDeclaredMethods("doCall")[0].code.text
// prints: { return (p.twice() * p) }
```

still, it might be useful as it is if you just want to take a quick look

AND, if you have too much time on your hands and don't know what to do you could write your own `org.codehaus.groovy.ast.GroovyCodeVisitor` to pretty print it

OR, just steal an existing one like `groovy.inspect.swingui.AstNodeToScriptVisitor`

```
// file: example3.groovy
def c = {w->
  [1,2,3].each {
    println "$it"
    (1..it).each {x->
      println 'this seems' << ' somewhat closer' << ''' to the 
      original''' << " $x"
    }
  }
}
def node = c.metaClass.classNode.getDeclaredMethods("doCall")[0].code
def writer = new StringWriter()
node.visit new groovy.inspect.swingui.AstNodeToScriptVisitor(writer)
println writer
// prints: return [1, 2, 3].each({
//     this.println("$it")
//     return (1.. it ).each({ java.lang.Object x ->
//         return this.println('this seems' << ' somewhat closer' << ' to the \n      original' << " $x")
//     })
// })
```

now.
if you want the **original**, exact, runnable code ... you are out of luck
i mean, you could use the source line information, but last time i checked, it wasn't really getting them right

```
// file: example1.groovy
....
def code = a.metaClass.classNode.getDeclaredMethods("doCall")[0].code
println "$code.lineNumber $code.columnNumber $code.lastLineNumber $code.lastColumnNumber"
new File('example1.groovy').readLines()
... etc etc you get the idea.
```

line numbers shuld be at least near the original code though

Comment: I don't understand what 'script available in the classpath AT RUNTIME' exactly means? It doesn't work yet (ClassNode is `null`), but I have all the sources available. Do I have to add the location of the script in the classpath of the Groovy project?

Comment: @Julian means the .groovy file should be in the classpath.
the getClassNode() will basically load the file, and compile it again with a special hook to save the relevant ast node, and return it

Comment: @jpertino Any thoughts on how you would do that in a Grails environment?  I have a Config.groovy file that is on the class path during integration tests but it isn't during run-app.

Comment: Irrelevant for Jenkins - Just to say that as far as I tried I could not make it work there - probably the classes are not available in jenkins slave runtime.

Answer (score 6):

That isn't possible in groovy.  Even when a groovy script is run directly, without compiling it first, the script is converted into JVM bytecode.  Closures aren't treated any differently, they are compiled like regular methods.  By the time the code is run, the source code isn't available any more.