# Getting the contents of closure, in groovy

Tags: groovy

I'm new to Groovy. I want to achieve this:

```
def a = { assert 1 == 1 }

def method(def a)
{
    println a
}
method(a)
```

The `println` now prints `ConsoleScript1$_run_closure1@72e9108f`. But I wish it would print `assert 1 == 1`. Is that possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [print the closure definition/source in Groovy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263008/print-the-closure-definition-source-in-groovy)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the [answer I linked to as a duplicate of this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263008/print-the-closure-definition-source-in-groovy), if you save:

```
import groovy.inspect.swingui.AstNodeToScriptVisitor

def a = { assert 1 == 1 }

def method( def a ) {
  new StringWriter().with { writer ->
    a.metaClass.classNode.getDeclaredMethods("doCall")[0].code.visit new AstNodeToScriptVisitor( writer )
    println "{\n$writer}"
  }
}

method( a )
```

to a file `test.groovy` then do:

```
groovy test.groovy
```

You get the output:

```
{
assert 1 == 1 : null
return null
}
```

Which is as close as you're going to get I think... Without using the positional data in the  `code` variable (which is a [Groovy Statement class](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/org/codehaus/groovy/ast/stmt/Statement.html)) to get the line/col numbers and parse the file as text to extract it...

Comment: This works. But if you call `replaceAll` method like this: `"{$writer}".replaceAll(/ (null)|(return)|\n|:|/,"")` I'm getting cleaner output: `{assert 'someting' == 2 }`

Comment: In grails this seems to be not working. I'm passing the closure from controller to service. I have defined the `method` in the service. When I try to call `method(closure)`, I get this error: `Cannot invoke method getDeclaredMethods() on null object`. Where things going wrong?

Comment: Ahh..  You didn't say this was in Grails.  I'm guessing when running in Grails, it can't find the originating `classNode` for the object, so returns `null`.  There may be a way round this, but it's probably easier to rethink your requirement.  Why is it you need this functionality?

Comment: We are creating a built test tool. I will pass the assert statement as closure to my service. In service I will execute the assert closure and look for errors. And finally we need to put the result into NoSql, where I need to save test case details. So what I thought was to get the contents from the passing closure itself but that doesn't seem to be working!

Comment: Could you pass the closure as a String, then evaluate the string (and run it) using something like `Eval.me`?  Then you have a closure, and the String that made it...

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for Javascript-like functionality where invoking toString() on a function would print its source code.

Groovy is compiled to JVM bytecode. The groovy compiler does not retain the source code in the compiled JVM class file.

Answer (score 0):

There is a well-known exemple written in Scala in the book "Programming in Scala" by Odersky & Co.

Basically, you have to :

- list the Files
- for each file matching *.groovy
- trim/grep the wanted lines

in [Groovy SDK](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html#eachFileMatch%28java.lang.Object,%20groovy.lang.Closure%29), there is a Groovy method `directory.eachFileMatch` that allow you to find the correct file, and a `File.filterLine()` method that allows you to grab the correct lines.

Comment: You can get that information out of the AST, which is going to give you better results than effectively using regexp to parse a source file