# Is it possible to retrieve lambda expression at runtime

Tags: java, lambda, bytecode, java-8

I was playing with Java8 Lambda last night and I was wondering if it is possible to retrieve the Lambda expression at runtime. In short and as far as I understood, Lambda expression are converted into (static) methods at runtime and then called using InvokeDynamics.

Let's take an example like this:

```
people.filter(person -> person.getAge() >= minAge);
```

where `filter` would be a custom method taking a `Predicate<T>`as a parameter.
Inside this `filter` method, how could I retrieve the argument in a form similar (or identical) to the Lambda expression (`person -> person.getAge() >= minAge`) in this case ?

I tried to read the generated bytecode of the argument's class using ASM5_BETA but I couldn't go further than using a ClassVisitor and a MethodVisitor to reach the method associated with the Lambda expression.

```
public <T> List<T> filter(Filter<T> expression) {
    try {
        Class<? extends Filter> expressionClass = expression.getClass();
        byte[] content = getClassContent(expressionClass);
        ClassReader classReader = new ClassReader(content);
        classReader.accept(new PredicateClassVisitor(), 0);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

private byte[] getClassContent(Class<? extends Filter> expressionClazz) throws  
               IOException {
    InputStream stream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
                           .getResourceAsStream(getClassName(expressionClazz.getName()));
    return IOUtils.toByteArray(stream);
}

private String getClassName(String expressionClazz) {
    return expressionClazz.substring(0, expressionClazz.indexOf('$'))
           .replace('.', '/') + ".class";
}

static class PredicateClassVisitor extends ClassVisitor {

    public PredicateClassVisitor() {
        super(Opcodes.ASM4);
    }

    @Override
    public MethodVisitor visitMethod(int i, String s, String s2, String s3, 
                                     String[] strings) {
        return new PredicateMethodVisitor();
    }
}

static class PredicateMethodVisitor extends MethodVisitor {

    public PredicateMethodVisitor() {
        super(Opcodes.ASM4);
    }

    @Override
    public void visitInvokeDynamicInsn(String name, String desc, Handle bsm,
                                       Object... bsmArgs) {
        for (Object object : bsmArgs) {
              System.out.println(" " + object.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure this is the right path to follow, and I was wondering if there were more appropriate tooling in ASM or in JDK8 for such a purpose.

Thanks for any advice ;-)
Best regards,
Xavier

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve here?  Until you explain this, it is difficult to advise you.

Comment: By "retrieve lambda expression" i take it you mean "generate". BTW the lambda call itself is not over InvokeDynamic, this is used only in the process of creating the lambda invocator object.

Comment: I'd like to capture the Lambda expression that was provided in the calling code, for logging purpose for example, or other usages later, maybe. I'm no talking about generating the bytecode instead of the JVM. From the example given above, in the `filter(Filter<T> expression)`method, I'd like to be able to revert the given `expression`argument to the `person -> person.getAge() >= minAge`  the lambda expression. Is this doable ?

Comment: You could try using Procyon to decompile the lambdas.

Comment: If you have the bytecode for the lambda then yes it is possible to transform it into _an_ equivalent piece of Java source. The ASM tools are the right fit for this (also asm-util and asm-tree).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You already know that lambda expressions are usually compiled into a synthetic method so you already know which code to decompile to get the lambda’s source code, or, well, something similar to the original code or even something looking completely different, depending on the particular code.

There is no reason why decompiling a lambda expressions should be easier than decompiling any other Java expression. Simple expressions might be easy to recover, especially when the code has debugging information, complex expressions are very likely to look different when decompiling, especially when the compiler applies optimizations to the code.

Comment: How do you know which code it is? The name of the lambda class (e.g. `$$Lambda$58/918965208`) does not correspond to the names of the lambda methods, which are numbered separately.

Comment: @OrangeDog: if you decompile that class, you’ll find out, which method it will invoke. In the case of this question, the OP has already tracked the method via the instantiation site. However, the point of this answer is that it is *not* easy or might even be impossible.

Comment: How have they found the instantiation site? From my reading of the question they happen to have only one lambda in the enclosing class, so `expressionClass` must be that one.

Comment: What are you basing this on? The code in the question starts from a `Filter` object that is a lambda and iterates over the bytecode of its enclosing class. Nowhere is there any hint that there's any consideration for dealing with the case where there are multiple lambdas in that class.

Comment: If you don't know what `Filter` is nor whether it's a lambda, then you clearly didn't read the question very carefully. It's the target method of the generated class that has the code in it - that's entirely what the question is about. And the class passed to the `ClassReader` is not synthetic, so there's no reason not to expect to find `invokedynamic` somewhere in it.

Comment: I claimed that `Filter` object was the lambda because it is. Read the code!

Comment: It is usual to comment on answers in order to explain what's wrong or lacking with them.

Comment: So what’s wrong with my answer, except that it doesn’t address your entirely different question? Almost everything you wrote is about the *question’s* code. If you think that the questioner’s code has to serve your goal, discuss it with *him*.

Comment: Yes, you've failed to comprehend the comments in the same way you failed to comprehend the question. The statement "you already know which code to decompile to get the lambda’s source code" is either incorrect or ambiguous. If you know how they know (previous responses indicate that you don't) then you should make it explicit.

Comment: @OrangeDog: the whole point of the answer is that *you can’t get the source code*. That’s it. How to find the target method of a generated class never was the topic. The introduction only suggests to the OP that “if you know the method, you know, it’s ordinary compiled code, not something special knowing the original source code”. Telling how to find the target method of a generated class, had no point, as it still doesn’t give the source code, the OP asked for.

Comment: Therefore, you should remove the first paragraph as misleading and ambiguous, and actually put the point of the answer in the answer.

Comment: @OrangeDog: you are the first one in the last 3½ years who find it misleading and ambiguous.

Comment: That's neither relevant, provable, nor statistically significant.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in some cases with Groovy, if this would help you: [Getting the contents of closure, in groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12671935/getting-the-contents-of-closure-in-groovy). [Geb](http://www.gebish.org/) actually uses this feature to highlight an assertion error inside an evaluated expression.