# Get a Groovy closure body text

Tags: templates, groovy, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

I am trying to create a Groovy class dynamically. I am using GroovyClassLoader and SimpleTemplateEngine to inject field and method definitions and generate my new class text representation and pass it to GroovyClassLOader.parseClass(). This works for class fields and also works for methods if the closures representing method bodies are injected as text. My problem is that I have no idea how to convert a Groovy closure to its text representation. I have found a couple examples here on StackOverflow:

[print the closure definition/source in Groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263008/print-the-closure-definition-source-in-groovy)

and

[Getting the contents of closure, in groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12671935/getting-the-contents-of-closure-in-groovy)

but both examples give me this exception:

```
Caught: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getDeclaredMethods() on null object
```

which means that metaClass.classNode is null

Here is my script:

```
c1 = '{return p1 + p2}'
c2 = '{return p1 * p2}'
data = [fields: ['p1': 'int', 'p2':'int'], methods: ['m1': c1, 'm2':c2], name: 'Agent']

templateText = '''

class $name
{
<%fields.each {%>    $it.value $it.key \n<% } %>
<%methods.each {%>   def $it.key() $it.value \n<% } %> 
}


'''

engine = new groovy.text.SimpleTemplateEngine()
template = engine.createTemplate(templateText)
result = template.make(data)
println result

GroovyClassLoader loader = new GroovyClassLoader()
Class cls = loader.parseClass(result.toString())
i = cls.newInstance()
i.p1 = 1
i.p2 = 2
i.setP2(10)
println i.m1()
println i.m2()
```

Comment: That script works for me...  What version of Groovy are you using? Or is there something not in the script you're trying to do that is failing?

Comment: @tim_yates The script works as it is ,but if I omit single quotes around my closures like this c1 = {return p1 + p2} the script throws an exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the second example you linked to, I can get this to (I think) work:

```
import groovy.inspect.swingui.AstNodeToScriptVisitor

String method( Closure a ) {
  new StringWriter().with { writer ->
    a.metaClass.classNode.getDeclaredMethods("doCall")[0].code.visit new AstNodeToScriptVisitor( writer )
    "{${writer.toString()}}"
  }
}

c1 = {p1 + p2}
c2 = '{return p1 * p2}'
data = [fields: ['p1': 'int', 'p2':'int'], methods: ['m1': method( c1 ), 'm2':c2], name: 'Agent']

templateText = '''

class $name
{
<%fields.each {%>    $it.value $it.key \n<% } %>
<%methods.each {%>   def $it.key() $it.value \n<% } %> 
}


'''

engine = new groovy.text.SimpleTemplateEngine()
template = engine.createTemplate(templateText)
result = template.make(data)
println result

GroovyClassLoader loader = new GroovyClassLoader()
Class cls = loader.parseClass(result.toString())
i = cls.newInstance()
i.p1 = 1
i.p2 = 2
i.setP2(10)
println i.m1()
println i.m2()
```

It does not work in the GroovyConsole, but it works if you save it as a script, and invoke it from the command line

Comment: At first your code gave me the same NullPointerException, bit I managed to get it to work by putting your method as a class member, and now it works beautifully. Thank you for the effort.

Comment: could you post a sample of what you did that worked?