# Access closure property names in the content block at runtime

Tags: geb

I want to evaluate my content blocks before running my test suite but the closures' property names  is in bytecode already.  I'm ooking for the *cleanest* solution (compared with parsing source manually).

Already tried solution outlined [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263008/print-the-closure-definition-source-in-groovy) (and I'd still wind up doing some RegEx/parsing) but could only get it to work via script execution engine.  It failed in IDE and GroovyConsole.  Rather than embedding a Groovy script in project's code, I thought I'd try using Geb's native classes.

Is building on the suggestion about extending Geb Navigators [here](http://fbflex.wordpress.com/2013/11/25/extending-geb-element/) viable for Geb's PageContentSupport class whose contentTemplates contain a LinkedHashMap of exactly what I need?  If yes, would someone provide guidance?  If no, any suggestions?

Comment: Can you please explain why you "want to evaluate my content blocks before running your test"? What use case are you trying to solve by doing so? I'm asking cause there might be a simpler solution to your problem than what you are trying to do.

Comment: Rather than using test results to repair deprecated/broken content, it would be much simpler to repair them prior to running our suites.  Think of it as unit tests for the navigator objects.  If there is something simpler, by all means, let me know.  Thanks, erdi!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is currently not possible to get hold of all content elements for a given page/module. Feel free to create an issue for this in [Geb's bug tracker](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GEB), but remember that all that Geb can provide is either a list of content element names or a map from these names to closures that create these elements.

Having that information isn't a generic solution to your problem because it's possible for content elements to take parameters and there are situations where your content elements will be available on the page only after some other actions are performed (for example you have to click on button to reveal a section of a page that uses ajax to retrieve it's content). So I'm afraid that simply going over all elements and checking if they don't throw any errors will not cut it.

I'm still struggling to see what would "evaluating" all content elements prior to running the suite buy you. Are you after verifying that your content elements still work to get a faster feedback than running the whole suite? I'm pretty sure that you won't be able to fully automate detection of content definitions that don't work anymore. In my view it will be more effort than it's worth.

Comment: Yes, the content element names is all I'd want so if you could provide the most direct route to that I'd be graetful, otherwise I can pass a literal list.  While I know it is not a generic "silver bullet" solution b/c DOM state may indicate false negatives as you suggested but more than 80% of my content is not state-dependent.  As far as what citing the problematic content before suite execution actually gets me, when over 50% of failures are due to dead content elements, even idendifying 80% of dead content definitions is preferable to fixing them at random based on false negatives.

Comment: Fair enough. Please create an issue in Jira for this.

Comment: Do you know if someone created a Geb issue for this?

Comment: Yes and it has been implemented in 2.2, see https://github.com/geb/issues/issues/369 and http://gebish.org/manual/current/#accessing-content-names