# Tracking down a Groovy method definition?

Tags: grails, groovy

Ruby gives you the ability to track down the file and line where a method is defined at runtime. So, for example, if you have an object named "obj" which has the ability to call the method "do_something", you could track its definition (in ruby 1.9 and above) with:

```
obj.method(:do_something).source_location
```

Does groovy have any equivalent capability? I'm trying to track down where a method is defined but it's proving very difficult.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you're just trying to see where a method is defined, why not step into the method call with your IDE's debugger?

Comment: In my case, intellij won't step into them. However, I think the following blurb from the Grails docs probably explains why "The GORM API has been formalized into a set of classes (GormStaticApi, GormInstanceApi and GormValidationApi) that get statically wired into every domain class at the byte code level. The result is better code completion for IDEs, better integration with Java and the potential for more GORM implementations for other types of data stores.". This kind of magic is what made troubleshooting Rails difficult. Sad it applies to Grails as well...I'd hoped for less magic.

Comment: This question along with answer might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263008/print-the-closure-definition-source-in-groovy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does groovy have any equivalent capability?

No.  You cannot interrogate an object and ask it a question like "If I invoke the save method and pass no arguments, what file contains the definition for the save method that will actually be invoked and at what line number is that definition.".  Neither the language nor the runtime provide facilities for that specifically.  You can do some things like interrogate the stack to find out where calls came from, but that isn't what is asked here.  I think the answer to your question is "no".

Comment: I wanted to add, that we don't do this in Groovy mainly because we compile to bytecode and the Java bytecode does not really provide this information through reflection. You can do a hack and get the information while you are in the method by throwing an exception and analyzing the trace, but that won't do here, since we are talking about a time before the call.